# Incorporating error values (uncertainties) into DBSCAN

Tags: clustering, dbscan

Suppose I have a set of coordinates (`x,y,z`), corresponding to ~800 points. I am currently using DBSCAN with a custom metric function (taking angles as an input, returning the Euclidean distance of the given two points) to cluster these points into groups:

```py
from sklearn.cluster import *
# ...
X = np.array([[long[i], lat[i], dm[i]] for i in range(len(frb))])

def dist(frb1, frb2):
    # Point A
    l1 = np.deg2rad(frb1[0])
    b1 = np.deg2rad(frb1[1])
    dm1 = frb1[2]

    # Point B
    l2 = np.deg2rad(frb2[0])
    b2 = np.deg2rad(frb2[1])
    dm2 = frb2[2]

    # Coordinate A
    x1 = dm1*np.cos(b1)*np.sin(l1)
    y1 = dm1*np.cos(b1)*np.cos(l1)
    z1 = dm1*np.sin(b1)

    # Coordinate B
    x2 = dm2*np.cos(b2)*np.sin(l2)
    y2 = dm2*np.cos(b2)*np.cos(l2)
    z2 = dm2*np.sin(b2)

    # Compute Euclidean distance
    distance = np.sqrt(((x1-x2)**2)+((y1-y2)**2)+((z1-z2)**2))
    return distance

# Cluster FRB repeaters
db = DBSCAN(eps=15, min_samples=2, metric=dist, n_jobs=-1).fit(X)
core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
labels = db.labels_
# ...
```

While it works OK and produces reasonable results, my measurements also allow me to return an error value (uncertainty) for the distance, which I would like to somehow incorporate into DBSCAN.

Does `sklearn` have an option for anything like this, or would I have to think of a more custom solution to get even more accurate results?